# Drools integration vs. traditional way

Tags: java, spring, integration, drools

I'm new to Drools. I read a lot of examples for using Drools in Java enterprise applications or Spring applications.I found that Drools supports integration with Spring and CDI by using annotations or application context in spring to create Kie objects like `KBase`, `KSession`, and `KContainer`. I can't get the advantage of using this integration methods. Other examples develop Spring applications but create these objects using the traditional way. [like this example](https://github.com/gratiartis/sctrcd-payment-validation-web)

What is the benefit of using Drools integration rather than the traditional way? Which way should I use? Does the injection of `KSession` implement any session management or pooling ?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no striking Performance Improvement in Spring Drools Integration vs Traditional way.

But as with any Spring Framework Module Spring Drools Integration will provide a Layer of Abstraction and Flexibility for your configurations of Drools.

Furthermore it enable to keep everything Simple by creating the necessary Drools objects easily with minimum configuration and lets you focus on the Core Rule Implementation.

Comment: Just to make sure, so this integration doesn't provide session management it's just for object creation